# If $1 \leq q < p$ whats a sequence in $\ell^{p}$ but not in $\ell^{q}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> If $1 \leq q < p$ whats a sequence in $\ell^{p}$ but not in $\ell^{q}$?

Having trouble understanding this, just looking for an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $x_n=n^{-\frac{1}{q}}$ will do.

Comment: $x = \left\{x_n \right\}$ is not in $\ell^q$ because $\|\ {x} \|_{\ell^{q}}\ = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |n^{- \frac{1}{q}}|^{q} \right)^{\frac{1}{q}} = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{n}| \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$ because this diverges?

Comment: Yes, the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: and from above, this is in $\ell^{p}$ because $\|\ {x} \|_{\ell^{p}}\ = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |n^{- \frac{1}{q}}|^{p} \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{n}|^{\frac{p}{q}} \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ because this converges?

Comment: because $\frac{p}{q} > 1$ so by $p$-test converges.

Comment: the fact that the whole series is raised to the $\frac{1}{q}$ doesn't effect the divergence for $\|\ x \|_{\ell^{q}}\ $?

Comment: This doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, thank you. If possible would you elaborate why that doesn't matter? It's not clear to me (albeit probably should be).

Comment: Because infinity raise to any positive power is still infinity.